# Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following this tutorial (Art auction hyperledger fabric):
https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain/auction.

At the "Invoke APIs and Usage" (CLI mode) step, I try to run the PostUsers command as follows:

user@user-VirtualBox:~/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin$ `./peer chaincode invoke -l golang -n mycc -c '{"Function": "PostUser", "Args":["100", "USER", "Ashley Hart", "TRD", "Morrisville Parkway, #216, Morrisville, NC 27560", "9198063535", "ashley@itpeople.com", "SUNTRUST", "00017102345", "0234678"]}'`

I get the following error:
CEST [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig folder

I ran this command:

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD
```

and now I have the following error:

```
panic: Fatal error when initializing core config : Error when reading core config file: Unsupported Config Type ""

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x555f5b365cc0, 0xc4201c81f0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
main.main()
    /home/user/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:94 +0x852
```

Comment: I don't know how works this example, but the problem is related with the lack of certificates that you need to start up the network and to communicate among the menbers (orderers, peers and clients). In other examples of the Hyperledger-Fabric project is explaines how to configure them. I suggest you to find where is configured your network or to visit the Fabric page where is explained how to build your first network. http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this date, this particular sample app has not yet been updated for Hyperledger Fabric v1.0. Basically the error you are seeing is due to the lack of msp certificates for the various roles involved in the sample. I suggest that you explore the [hyperledger/fabric-samples](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html) as they are aligned with the 1.0 release.

Comment: Okay! So the example I'm trying to run will not work until it's upgraded to version 1.0? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If there were updates, a notification would also be welcome in this post.